# How do I stop IIS mangling my error codes for Soap faults

Tags: web-services, iis, soap

We provide a webservice to a third-party that expects a 500 error when an application level error occurs.  When this happens we construct a piece of custom XML with the error details (eventcode etc) and return this as the synchronous response.

However, it seems that IIS is intercepting the 500 error and replacing our custom XML with a "pretty" html page.

Does anybody know how I can stop this from happening?  We have tried disabling custom errors in IIS and all we get back in that setup is a "an error occurred" string and now our custom XML.

**Notes:** IIS version 7 (Windows Server 2008) with a custom Handler we developed last week.

Comment: which version of IIS, and what is the underlying service stack (WCF, ASMX, something custom you rolled last week . . . )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** is to use [HttpResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors.aspx)

Here's what we're doing, something like this..

```
httpApplication.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
httpApplication.Response.Write(myCustomErrorString);
httpApplication.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
httpApplication.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

Thanks to [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/745738.aspx)